# Unable to display the exact HTML code with PHP for loop

Tags: php, html

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($item); $i++) {
    echo '<ul class="list1">';
    if ($i <= 1) {
        echo '<li>'.$item[$i].'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '<ul class="list2">';
    if ($i >= 2 && $i <= 7) {
    echo '<li>'.$item[$i].'</li>';
    }
echo '</ul>';
```

}

I tried to display the following HTML with only php(above code) however, it seems like it's not working as expected. How  can I display the exact same thing with php?

```
<ul class="list1">
                    <li>
                        <? echo $item[0];?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <? echo $item[1];?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="list2">
                    <li>
                        <? echo $item[2];?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <? echo $item[3];?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <? echo $item[4];?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <? echo $item[5];?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <? echo $item[6];?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <? echo $item[7];?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like this,

```html
<?php
$item = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($item); $i++) {
    if ($i < 1) {
        echo '<ul class="list1">';
    }
            if ($i <= 1) {
                echo '<li>'.$item[$i].'</li>';
            }
    if ($i == 1) {
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    if ($i == 2) {
        echo '<ul class="list2">';
    }
            if ($i >= 2 && $i <= 7) {
                echo '<li>'.$item[$i].'</li>';
            }
    if ($i == 7) {    
    echo '</ul>';
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the simplified syntax for the expected output

```
echo '<ul class="list1">';    
for ($i = 0; $i < count($item); $i++) {
    echo '<li>'.$item[$i].'</li>';
    if ($i == 1) {
        echo '</ul><ul class="list2">'';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use two for loop, first loop items from 0 to 1 in "list1", second loop items form 2 to 7 in "list 2"

```
echo '<ul class="list1">'
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++) {
        echo '<li>'.$item[$i].'</li>'
    }
echo '</ul>';

echo '<ul class="list2">'
    for ($i = 2; $i <= 7; $i++) {
        echo '<li>'.$item[$i].'</li>'
    }
echo '</ul>';
```